# Confused about two examples

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, subjects

I was reading about Subject-Verb agreement from a grammar book I have, and I came about some of these examples:

> 1.The *behavior* of the *children were* excellent. [Here *were* must be *was* in order to agree with *behavior*.]
> 2.Not *one* of his *lectures have ever* been printed.[The subject is *one*, not *lectures*; therefore, *have* should be *has*.]
> 3.By that time *two weeks' salary were due*.[Here again, the subject is *salary*, not *weeks*; therefore, *were* should be *was*.]
> 4.The quality of the mangoes *was* (not *were*) good.
> 5.The cost of all these articles *has* (not *have*) risen.
> 6.A series of lectures *has* (not *have*) been arranged on the subject
> 7.A variety of pleasing objects *charms* (not *charm*) the eye.

I understood the first three examples as there was explanation for them. In the fourth example, the subject is *quality* so we used singular verb. In the fifth example, *cost* is the subject and hence, we used singular verb again.

What I didn't get is the sixth and seventh example. Is the subject in sixth example is *series*? what is the subject in the seventh example?

Comment: *A series* is clearly singular. *A variety of pleasing objects* is, however, trickier. Arguably, you can use either *charms* or *charm* here. See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44942/a-variety-of-x-is-vs-a-variety-of-x-are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [American Heritage of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/series).

> Series is both a singular and a plural form. When it has the singular sense of "one set," it takes a singular verb, even when series is followed by of and a plural noun: A series of lectures is scheduled. When it has the plural sense of "two or more sets," it takes a plural verb: Two series of lectures are scheduled: one for experts and one for laypeople.

As regards **a variety of** [Collins COBUILD English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/variety) explains:

> After **a variety of** you use a plural form of a verb: A variety of treatment methods exist.

But when it comes to **variety of** you use singular:

> Each variety of tree has its own name.

Comment: I agree that "series" can be either singular or plural.  In this example it is singular.

Comment: Regarding the rule given for "variety", I would like to say that I, as a native speaker of English, have never heard of this exception.  I would use the singular verb, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Usernew,[Please don't accept an answer too quickly](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Comment: @user1008646 So would I; but I think that over the last generation 'variety' in contexts like this has been evolving into what CGEL calls a "number-transparent quantificational noun" like *lot* or *rest*.

Comment: @LucianSava I will keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0):

The subject in example 6 is "series", which in this case is singular.

The subject in example 7 is "variety", singular.

Comment: if the subject is "variety" in example 7, then why we have used plural form of the verb?

Comment: For regular English verbs, we add "s" for the third-person singular.    The boy eats his breakfast.  The boys eat their breakfast.